# Error Opening Crystal Report in ASP.NET

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

i am trying to open a crystal report in my website but its giving an error 
Here is the code i have tried

```
 protected void report_view(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
    TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
    TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
    ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    Tables CrTables;

    cryRpt.Load("C:\\Report1.rpt");

    crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "local";
    crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "MyEmployees";
    crConnectionInfo.UserID = "MYLAPTOP\\HOME";

    CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
    {
        crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
        crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
    }

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

and here is the error shown in CrystalReportViwer

```
  Failed to open the connection. Failed to open the connection. Report1 {1222DD0B-C24E-  4E66-8EE1-7ED7F5F0D6B4}.rpt
```

i am using visual studio 2010 with Crystal Reports 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are missing a password when declaring the connection details. Try adding it:

```
crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "local";
crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "MyEmployees";
crConnectionInfo.UserID = "MYLAPTOP\\HOME";
crConnectionInfo.Password = "Password"; //Swap with real password of course
```

Ensure that all file paths and file names are also correct.

Alternatively you can look into the [**SetDataBaseLogon() method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227750%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: database is not password protected. . .

Comment: personally i doubt the Server Name , database is local so thats why i am putting server name as local, same as in SqlServer UserID is also same as in SqlServer User Name

Comment: SetDataBaseLogon() method worked for me , thanks @Conrad Lotz